# ion-button is not working while using in div

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, button

I am using ionic angular,ion-button is not working in some parts of code,but it is working in some parts of code.The button is not getting clicked.

```
<div class="ion-page" id="main">
  <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-button slot="start" expand="block" >
        <ion-menu-button ></ion-menu-button>
        <!-- <ion-menu-button (onclick)="gotoLogin()"></ion-menu-button> -->
      </ion-button>
      <ion-title>Capture Image</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
    <ion-button (click)="goToProfile()">Profile Page</ion-button>

    </ion-list>

    
  </ion-content>
</div>


<ion-menu side="start" menuId="first" contentId="main">
  <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar color="primary">
      <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-button (click)="goToProfile()">Profile Page</ion-button>
      <ion-button>Capture Image</ion-button>
      <ion-item>Community</ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-menu>
```

The button in div is not working where as button in ion-menu is working.
What is the problem with this?

Comment: Have you inspected it in your browser? Most of the times its `CSS` overlapping issue

Comment: There appears to be nothing wrong with the code you've posted.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this, according to https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/item

```html
<ion-list>
  <!-- Item as a Button -->
  <ion-item button (click)="buttonClick()">
    <ion-label>
      Button Item
    </ion-label>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```